# Nothing shows up when i run Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When i run jupyter notebook it just shows up blank

I checked Console for errors and it showed me this:
[Console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOmbi.png)

This is the line that the above Error message is referring to:
[Error message line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX4jB.png)

Here is the URL bar if you need it (this is what the URL bar shows when i launch Jupyter notebook):
[URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOmbi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script object_detection_tutorial.ipynb
```

to convert .ipynb to .txt, then copied the code to a .py file